# Modernizr .hidden class

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, hidden, modernizr

I just included Modernizr in my project, but it adds the .hidden class to my html tag. This causes Bootstrap to hide the entire html tag, which is, well, not that useful..

Does anybody know why it adds the .hidden class to the html?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've used Modernizr with Bootstrap and never had that. What Modernizr tests are you using? Or are you just including the `<script>` tag and it gives this problem? A hacky solution might be `html.hidden { display: initial; visibility: initial; }`

Answer (score 8):

I encountered the exact same issue and found two solutions.

Looking through the [Modernizr download page](https://modernizr.com/download), it looks like the "hidden" class is added when Modernizr is checking for and detects support for the `[hidden]` attribute.

Simply make a build of Modernizr with detection for the `[hidden]` attribute omitted.

If you actually **need** to detect it, and overriding Bootstrap's CSS rule with your own on `html.hidden` isn't something you want to do, you can configure Modernizr with a [class prefix](https://modernizr.com/docs#classprefix) to prevent the name clashing.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I usually use a lean version of modernizr but during development I use the whole library and leave grunt to detect the features I am using. This is the first time I encounter that issue (probably cause I didn't use modernizr 3 with bootstrap 3 before)